# dbRef closure is bypassed

Tags: swift

I am working firebase with swift. However, when the line **dbRef.child("json").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)** is run, the closure behind that is not executed. It directly jump to the end of the function.

My database do have a hierarchy like this.
json/(radomID)/url:"String"

May I know anyway I can solve/debug the problem?

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class SaveLoadService {

var delegate: gameRecordProtocol?

var gameRecordArray = [gameRecord]()



static func getPhotos(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Void {

    //Getting a reference to the database
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()


    //Make the db call
    dbRef.child("json").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in


        var jsonUrl: String = ""

        //get the list of snapshot
        let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]

        if let snapshots = snapshots {



            for snap in snapshots {

                print(snap)

            }

        }

        // after parsing the snapshots, call the completion closure
        completion(jsonUrl)
    }
   } 

}
```

Comment: It will not execute instantly. You need to give it some time. And once data retrieved from server it will execute,

Comment: thanks. but how can I know if I retrieve the data successfully or not?

Comment: It will automatically get call when you got data from server

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it! 
Actually, I want to have some computation with the value that I am going to download from firebase. How can I solve the delay problem?
Now the code continues to run without finishing retrieving the data so return nil.

Comment: You can not solve that delay problem because it's an Asynchronous call. But you can show loader while retrieving data from server. This way you can stop user to performa ay action on screen.

Comment: it's returning `nil` because either server don't have data you are requesting or probably you are executing wrong query to get the data.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand and now I want to do what you suggest.
I am planning to create a progress bar. But I don't know how to get the progress when making a db call.